# How to select and print sected whole piece of block of xml by xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

I have a XML data source  which has a tag named text, in this tag it contains a full html. So I want to get this html and print in Jasper report by xpath . Is it possible to select a piece of block of XML by xpath ?

example:

```
 <section>
        <text><table class="gridtable">
    <tr>
        <th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th><th>Info Header 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text 1A</td><td>Text 1B</td><td>Text 1C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text 2A</td><td>Text 2B</td><td>Text 2C</td>
    </tr>
    </table></text> 
    </section>
```

Thanks,
Nikhil Soni

Answer (score 0):

Xpath expression:

> string(//section/text)

Comment: It does no work, gives null. Is it tested ? I am using xpath in Jasper report where we need to provide xpath to fetch values from xml data source.

Comment: Nikhil soni Try this please. I would personally use string manipulation to do what you need, its very easy

Comment: I tried it. not working in jasper. I have done this from Java by converting xml node to string and pass to Jasper. Is it ok?